# Pathfinding with portals?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, portals, heuristics

I'm not making a game with portals in it (one way or bidirectional). These portals instantly teleport characters from one location to another. How would I implement pathfinding?

Here's an animation showing the portals in action, and different paths taken: http://www.makeitshareit.com/animation/86137

How do I perform pathfinding whilst taking in the possibility of using the portals as shortcuts? If I just use A*, the portals may wreak havoc with the [admissibility requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic). How can I also make it reasonably efficient, such as avoiding quadratic complexity with respect to the number of portals?

Comment: Alright perhaps I'm being antsy...but what portals are you referring to if you are *not* making a game with portals in it?

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052720) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428331)

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of questions from stackoverflow.com, as BlueRaja commented.